# Can I count the number of users matching a value in a multiple value key?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, user-meta

I'm trying to find the number of users having a certain value in a custom field. The problem is that this custom field allow multiple values. 
This code works well when the meta_key allows only one value, but how can I get it work with multiple values?

```
$args = array('meta_key' => 'fruits_user_like', 'meta_value' =>'apple');
$users = get_users($args);
$number_of_users = count($users);
```

Comment: Don't use serialized data in custom fields if you are going to sort by it or use it for search purposes. Create a custom key for each value, don't cram everything into one key, either as a string or serialized data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with serialized data as your meta_value, that sucks, as Pieter suggested, it's best not to.

However if there is no way around the serialization problem then I wonder if a `meta_query` using a `compare` value of `LIKE` might help...

Example:

```
//psuedo serialized data... (e.g. value of meta_key = fruits_user_like)
//a:4:{i:0;s:5:"apple";i:1;s:6:"orange";i:2;s:6:"banana";i:3;s:31:"serialized_data_sucks_sometimes";}

$users = get_users(   
    array(   
        'meta_query' => array(  
            array(  
                'key'   => 'fruits_user_like',
                'value' => array(
                    'apple', 
                    'orange', 
                    'banana', 
                    'serialized_data_sucks_sometimes'
                ),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )    
    )    
);
```

...I wonder.

The above won't work with a `compare` value of `LIKE`, we need to use `REGEXP` and pass a regular expression as the value.

Try the following:

```
$args = array(   
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(    
            'key'   => 'fruits_user_like',
            'value' => '(apple|orange|banana)',
            'compare' => 'REGEXP'
        )
    ),
    'count_total' => true
);

$users = new WP_User_Query($args);

print_r( $users->get_total() );
```

Switch to using to **[`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)**, it's more fitting in this instance because we can pass a `count_total` parameter and then call the method `WP_User_Query::get_total()`

Comment: It should work, but as we all know, it is not very reliable, and `LIKE` is quite expensive operations :-)

Comment: Yep... I make no concessions for performance, if he's _damned_ so to speak, then his options are but a few... either refactor or wear the perf hit.